# StreamReader — File Parser — Check Line Contents

Tags: c#, tokenize, streamreader

I have successfully got the C# `StreamReader` working:

```
using (StreamReader fileParser = new StreamReader(tbFileSelection.Text))
{
  String line = fileParser.ReadToEnd();
  Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

I am currently writing each line of the file to the console. I now wish to go through each line and look for a specific tag — [TAG1] if the line starts with [TAG1] — I wish to display  the entire line in the console. Please note, the file is not XML-based. Can anyone suggest a way forward with this idea? I believe I need to tokenize the string Line?

Comment: `foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(path).Where(l=>l.StartsWith("[TAG1]"))) Console.WriteLine(line);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `StartsWith` method to do filtering from lines:

```
lines = File.ReadLines(tbFileSelection.Text)
            .Where(line => line.StartsWith("[TAG1]"));

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: Is lines in the context of "lines =" an array? If so in C# how do you declare an array of an indefinite length?

Comment: @JHarley1: No, it IEnumerable<string>, you can use List<string> or dynamic length

Comment: Right I have now got:  IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(tbFileSelection.Text).Where(line => line.StartsWith("[TAG1]"));

            foreach (line in lines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            } I am just having problems with my "line" definition.